# mithril hello world MVC example not working

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, mithril.js

I am having trouble getting the Mithril hello world MVC example working.

Here is my code, as copied from the [Mitrhil homepage](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/). Note the only change I made was to swap the `m.request({method: "GET", url: "pages.json"});` method call to a manually generated pages object.

```
//namespace
var app = {};

//model
app.PageList = function() {
    var pages = [];
    pages.push({title: 'page 1', url: '/page1.html'});
    pages.push({title: 'page 2', url: '/page2.html'});
    return pages;
};

//controller
app.controller = function() {
    var pages = app.PageList();
    return {
        pages: pages,
        rotate: function() {
            pages().push(pages().shift());
        }
    }
};

//view
app.view = function(ctrl) {
    return [
        ctrl.pages().map(function(page) {
            return m("a", {href: page.url}, page.title);
        }),
        m("button", {onclick: ctrl.rotate}, "Rotate links")
    ];
};

//initialize
m.module(document.getElementById("example"), app);
```

As you can see, my example above in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/jug68s27/) doesn't work, but another Mitrhil example, the todo app [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/L0r2yhpg/) works fine.

I think it would make sense for the basic MVC Mitrhil example to work simply like the Todo app does, and possibly link to a jsFiddle or CodePen example for users to fork, similar to in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some calls to `pages` which should have been variable references instead, since it's an Array. Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/jug68s27/4/

`ctrl.pages()` -> `ctrl.pages`

`pages().push(pages().shift())` -> `pages.push(pages.shift())`

Comment: Thanks, does this mean the example on the Mithril website homepage is incorrect too? as wouldn't  `m.request({method: "GET", url: "pages.json"})` return an array, or does that return a method. Either way might be a good idea to have a simple jsFiddle link to fork on their site, either using the array, or returning data from a sample endpoint.

Comment: `m.request` returns a GetterSetter, which is a function, so the problem occurred when you changed that to an array. Good idea with a jsFiddle for the examples. If you want, open an issue for that on github (or make a pull request)!

Answer (score 0):

In this example the value not redraw because you didn't use **m.prop**, if you want that the value change you cas use
  `var pages = m.prop('');`

**Now** you can use `pages().push` or `ctrl.pages().map` because m.prop is a function!!!!
Remember this it's very important, you will use it a lot